# css ::before & ::after border alignment

Tags: html, css

I want to give border like this. Please check below code.

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

button:before {
  content: "";
  border: 4px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  left: -9px;
  top: -8px;
  width: 106%;
  height: 125%;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner-message">
  <button>Hover to change color</button> <br/><br/>
  <button>Hover to change color lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</button>
</div>
```

My problem is when content increases inside button border alignment  also getting disturbed. Please give me solution on this.

Comment: why are you doing a border with `::before`?

Comment: because some buttons have normal border. and I want to give such type of border on hover. Please check updated example.

Comment: so why not working with `box-shadow` or `outline`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine dynamic and static values together `width: calc(100% + 7px);`

```
$blue: #0084ff;
$blue-darker: darken($blue, 5);
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

button {
  background: $blue-darker;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  &:before {
    content: "";
    border: 4px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    left: -7px;
    top: -6px;
    width: calc(100% + 7px);
    height: 111%;
    border-radius: 30px;
  }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/93uq0fkb/1/)

Comment: This is more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @thingEvery which part you find complicated ?

Comment: The `calc()` part. You can achieve the same result with `padding`.

Comment: @thingEvery even padding is not needed, you can do without

Answer (score 2):

No need complex calculation. Remove the width and consider `right` like your did with `left`. Same thing for height:

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

button:before {
  content: "";
  border: 4px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  left: -8px;
  top: -8px;
  right: -8px;
  bottom: -8px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner-message">
  <button>Hover to change color</button> <br/><br/>
  <button>Hover to change color lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add some `padding` to the border and adjust the `top` and `left` values to fit your font size.

```
$blue: #0084ff;
$blue-darker: darken($blue, 5);

body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

 button {
    background: $blue-darker;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 8px 14px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;


    &::before{
      content: "";
      border: 4px solid red;
      position: absolute;
      left: -8px;
      top: -8px;
      padding: 4px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border-radius: 30px;
    }
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d4cugr07/